# How to correctly update the adapter list of a RecyclerView after drag & drop?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room

I have a RecyclerView with items fetched from a Room database. The movement of the items is implemented with ItemTouchHelper. Each item has a position attribute which is changed correctly when moving the items. After moving the item an update is send to the database, but this is not represented in the RecyclerView.

viewModel:

```
val items: LiveData<List<Item>> = database.getItemsByPosition()

fun movePositions(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int) {
    
    // code to update positions here

    uiScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            databaseDao.updateItems(items.value!!)
        }
    }
}
```

databaseDao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM item_table ORDER BY position")
fun getItemsByPosition(): LiveData<List<Item>>
```

In fragment on onCreateView:

```
viewModel.items.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {

        it?.let {
            for (item in it) {
                Log.d("Observer", "Item ${item.id}, position ${item.position}")
            }
            adapter.submitList(it)
        }
    })
```

The Fragment has an observer for items. By using Log.d, I verified that items updated correctly, but when submitting nothing changes. Since submitList tends to ignore changes to the same list, I tried `adapter.submitList(ArrayList(it))` as well, but to no avail.

When I move item 1 (position A) to position B, it seems that item 2 (originally on position B) moves to position A and item 1 just moves one up or down. This does not correspond to the logs, and when reloading the view, the order is as it should be. Why does it not update correctly with drag and drop?

To make it more clear, here is a short [demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhKu7.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using LiveData straight from the Room database seemed to cause the unexpected behavior, so I tried solving my problem by not using the LiveData straight from the database.

Now instead of

```
val items: LiveData<List<Item>> = databaseDao.getItemsByPosition()
```

I use

```
private val _items = MutableLiveData<List<Item>>()
    val items: LiveData<List<Item>>
        get() = _item

init {
    uiScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _items.postValue(databaseDao.getItemsByPosition())
        }
    }
}

fun movePositions(fromPosition: Int, toPosition: Int) {

    // code to update positions here

    uiScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            databaseDao.updateItems(items.value!!)
        }
    }
}
```

This solves the movement of the items. This does mean that that the items are not always in sync with the Room database anymore. E.g. adding a new item to the database did not show in the RecyclerView. I solved this by adding following line after the database insert.

```
_items.postValue(databaseDao.getItemsByPosition())
```

While this does not explain the original problem I had, this is a workaround and hopefully of use to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like RecyclerView.NotifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: Adding `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`, did help in making sure the items are displayed correctly in the end, but the problem of the animation still remains. Now the items still move the same way, but after the (incorrect) animation the data on items just changes to the right order. While this is a step in the right direction, this does not solve the issue of the incorrect animation.